# Jmeter - have url that leads to a file, but don't want to download it

Tags: http, jmeter

I have a server that I need to load test - I just need to see how long it takes to establish a connection to the server

To test this out I was given a url (something like: http://crl.test.hr/test.crl) that leads directly to a 5Mb file (test.crl)- so when I run my JMeter script, it not only establishes a connection to the server, but also downloads test.crl

that file is 5~Mb in size so it botches my response times (I dont have a download link so powerful to handle 360 5Mb file downloads in a minute)

I'm trying to avoid that but cant seem to find a way (using JMeter 3.1) for JMeter to only establish a connection to the server and then disconnect without downloading the file

Is it possible ?

Comment: just to add, I have to use the supplied url (http://crl.test.hr/test.crl) because everything else on that server isnt publicly available and returns 403 forbidden

Comment: Any feedback on answer , if ok it should be accepted and upvoted so that others can trust it? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You could workaround this by:

- Setting a short response timeout on the [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request)
- Adding a [response assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion) with "ignore status" checked and a text that check that response contains a ReadTimeout (not something else which would indicate an issue)

Another option is to use [byte-range](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Range_requests) if your server handle it and make JMeter only download few bytes:

- Add a Header manager and set :

> Range: bytes=0-100

Another option is to use Head method instead of Get if your server handles it

Comment: "Another option is to use Head method instead of Get if your server handles it"

hey, this seems to be working but when I go to see the response data in "View results tree", its all empty - is that okay ? response times vary between each request so everything seems ok, its just weird that there is no response data

Comment: Yes it is okay provided you're not interested in the impact of bandwidth on response times. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/HEAD

Answer (score 1):

You can use [TCP Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#TCP_Sampler) it just sends the request and wait for any response:

> The TCP Sampler opens a TCP/IP connection to the specified server. It then sends the text, and waits for a response.

For example GET request - Put just the Server Name/IP in `Server Name or IP` field and the full path with parameter put in `Text to Send` field

Answer (score 0):

You also have an option to use [HTTP Raw Request](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/RawRequest/) plugin.

It gives you an option to limit response buffer size by changing `kg.apc.jmeter.samplers.ReceiveBufferSize` property:

> Request reads response using buffer with default length of 4KB. You may override this value by setting JMeter property kg.apc.jmeter.samplers.ReceiveBufferSize in bytes.

Just add plugin and add Sampler `jp@gc - HTTP Raw Request`.